# Converting number to string and then comparing in php

Tags: php, regex

EDIT: 
Converted to using round which returns a float

I am converting am rounding a number to 2 decimals using round function

My question is about this line of code below:

Could their be rounding errors or unexpected behavior that could cause this condition to be true when it should not be?

```
if ($cc_amount > $total)
```

FULL CODE:

```
    $cc_amount = round($this->sale_lib->get_payment_total('credit'),2);
    $total = round($this->sale_lib->get_total(),2);

    //Since they are floats could there be rounding errors?
    if ($cc_amount > $total)
    {
        $this->_reload(array('error' => 'Credit card payment is greater than total');
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just compare the numbers as numbers?

Comment: why not just `$rounded = round($num, 2)`? formatting to string and then regexing is massively inefficient. and consider that as strings, `'9' < '12'` is false if you do things wrong.

Comment: If you are concerned about rounding, you can round on the fly: `if(round($cc_amount,2)>round($total,2))`

Comment: I am wondering if PHP will compare them as numbers even though they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing as to what you are doing.

When comparing strings it could grab each character's ascii code and compare them one at a time from the left most character to the right so something like 823 > 2015.

If I were to compare I'd keep them in number format and calculate each amount given approximately like so.

```
function to_decimals($number, $decimals = 2)
{
    if (is_numeric($number))
    {
        $updown = (10^$decimals)
        return round(($number * $updown))/$updown;
    }
    else
    {
        return -999999;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if PHP will compare them as numbers even though they are strings.

Comment: @ChrisMuench: Why don't you make simple tests to be sure?

Comment: It seems to work fine. I am more concerned if floats are compared could it turn out to have a rounding error and cause incorrect data

Comment: You are able to round one way or another and you can always round up, down, nearest, or really however you want.
I'm not sure how it would come up with an error there, but if your comparing numbers, from personal experience, it's always best to keep it as a number.